# Sort images before display based on condition

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, jinja2

I have a list of images I'd like to display and I would like to give them different coloured borders based on conditions. Also, **I'd like the images with the same color border to be grouped together** on the page.

Currently, this is how I display images.

```
<div class="zoom">
{% if image in image_list_1 %}
<img class='img' style="border-style:solid;border-color:deeppink;border-width: 4px ;" src="{{ image_url }}" loading="lazy" />

{% elif image in image_list_2 %}
<img class='img' style="border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(20, 149, 255);border-width: 4px ;" src="{{ image_url }}" loading="lazy" />

{% elif ((image in image_list_1) and (image in image_list_2)) %}
<img class='img' style="border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(49, 189, 0);border-width: 4px ;" src="{{ image_url }}" loading="lazy" />

{% else %}
<img class='img' src="{{ image_url }}" loading="lazy" />

{% endif %}
</div>
```

The above code simply puts all images with borders on the page in the order in which they get images. The grouping part is missing. How can I do it?

Comment: I would create 4 arrays of images, grouping the different images according to your conditions and logic.

Then I would loop over those arrays, and use DOM Manipulations to print them onto the document in the order you like.

Comment: This idea helps.. I can first add each image to different lists and then display lists one by one. That should do the trick. Could you tell me how to create lists/ any resources that would help, in jinja2? I'm a beginner actually @Narxx

Comment: I have no idea what `jinja2` is :) I could implement a similar thing in other languages, but this should be easy enough to Google. Good luck!